# How do I stop kernel messages being visible on tty12 and thus to unauthenticated users?

Tags: linux, terminal, console

In Linux, before a window manager is running, if I hit the Windows key from a console (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), I can see kernel messages.  I would like to disable the kernel messages from displaying at all since sensitive information could be displayed even before a user is authenticated on the system.

Where do I make this change, `/etc/inittab`, or some other file?

I did a grep for 12 in `/etc` and see `/etc/rc.conf` (I'm on gentoo) and the number of ttys allocated is 12.  I am changing this to the number I actually have assigned `getty`s which is 6, hoping that will disable the kernel output since there should not be anything on that tty.  It is interesting though why the kernel output is just on `tty12` and not 7 - 12.

Comment: Rename the title to a round sentence. Since you have more than 300 rep, also you have a reopen vote about your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was syslog, I merely commented / removed these lines:

```
sed -i "s/^log { source(src); destination(console_all); };/#log { source(src); destination(console_all); };/" /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf

sed -i "s/^destination console_all/#destination console_all/" /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

The first one is required, the second one was just to cleanup and ensure I'm not using it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

That is a kernel command line option, set at boot. It's usually part of grub's configuration (in `/etc/default/grub`). Look for this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"`

After editing, you'll need to run `update-grub` with root privileges. Make sure your `/boot` partition is mounted before the update, if it's a separate partition.

Comment: Ah, so, since it's part of the kernel, then if I build my own kernel, I can simply disable it there too, right?

Comment: Actually, not sure how I missed this earlier when grepping, but /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf has the configuration to log to tty12 by default.  I will update that, but in addition, I should ensure that tty12 isn't configured to display anything.